# How to resize partition with "raid" flag

Tags: filesystems, raid, mdadm

Keep in mind that this question is not about how to resize/grow a RAID array or RAID partition.

I have a 4 TB partition (`/dev/sdb1`) on a 8 TB physical HDD (`/dev/sdb`). The partition has the flag `raid` because it is part of an incomplete RAID1 array. There is no other partition on that HDD.

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 7,3 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA HDWG180 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1F88C10B-74C7-B940-801A-556C5F5E2DA8

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 7814037134 7814035087  3,7T Linux RAID
```

I want to resize that partition to use the full 8TB HDD without loosing the data in the partition.

If this would be a usual filesystem (e.g. `ext4`) I would know what to do. But with a `Linux RAID` type I am not sure if this is a filesystem or not. Or does the RAID1 on the higher level influence all that.

Of course a "simple" `mdadm --grow` does not work because the underlying partition (`/dev/sdb1`) is to small.

```
$ sudo mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --size=max
mdadm: component size of /dev/md0 has been set to 3906885447K
```

**Background info**:
The RAID1 currently has no second device/partition - it is missing.
In the last consequence I want to grow the "higher-level" RAID1 partition (`/dev/md0`; assembled from `/dev/sdb1` only, with a missing/failed/removed second device).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing magic about the raid flag ( in fact, all it does is change the partition table type, and Linux doesn't really give a fig about partition table types ).  Partitions are partitions, and the contents are the contents.  Resize the partition just as you would for an ext4 filesystem, then `mdadm --grow` can grow the raid array to use the additional space.  Then you'll want to grow whatever is inside the raid array.